# Curve Fitting error for two arrays

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have two arrays:

```
x=[ 2180000; 6070000; 12700000; 16600000; 25000000; 29400000; 32200000; 36100000; 41600000; 43900000; 47200000; 55000000 ]

y= [ 1.0e-07*0.0953; 1.0e-07*0.1060; 1.0e-07*0.1220; 1.0e-07*0.1290; 1.0e-07*0.1480; 1.0e-07*0.1580; 1.0e-07*0.1880; 1.0e-07*0.2510; 1.0e-07*0.3210; 1.0e-07*0.3510; 1.0e-07*0.4470; 1.0e-07*0.6090]
```

I used this custom equation:

```
y=a*exp(-b/(4.14e-21))*exp(((3.2e-9)*(x))/((2)*(1.38e-23)*(300)))
```

The problem that I have is:

> NaN computed by model function, fitting cannot continue. Try using or tightening upper and lower bounds on coefficients.

Comment: Remove the data from both `x` and `y` where you have `NaNs`?

Comment: Sorry, I want to find the values of a and b in the equation. I have x and y as known parameters.

Comment: Which function/commmand/technique are you using for curve fitting?

Comment: In Matlab Program, there is a curve fitting tool. This is the one that I used

Comment: @HishamAlghamdi please be more specific about how this error occurs. Edit the code where you try to apply the curve fit into your question.